# Autenticação utilizando CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

estou começando a utilizar o codeigniter, e possuo uma dúvida.

Na view, tenho 2 formularios, um para login e outro para cadastro:

```
<form id="login" method="post">
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <p><label>email:</label> <input type="email"/></p>
    <p><label>senha:</label> <input type="password"/></p>
    <p><label>enviar</label> <input type="submit"/></p>
</form>

<form id="cadastro" method="post">
    <legend>Cadastro</legend>
    <p><label>nome:</label> <input type="text"/></p>
    <p><label>email:</label> <input type="email"/></p>
    <p><label>senha:</label> <input type="password"/></p>
    <p><label>Repita a senha:</label> <input type="password"/></p>
    <p><label>enviar</label> <input type="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

E no controller, tenho os dois métodos, de login e cadastro

```
public function login(){
    echo 'chamou login';
}

public function cadastro(){
    echo 'chamou cadastro';
}
```

Porém não sei como chamar os métodos certos, ou seja, login quando eu preencher os campos do login e cadastro quando eu preencher os campos de cadastro. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos supor que seu arquivo de controller chama "user.php"

Ficaria assim:

```
<form id="login" method="post" action="http://www.seudominio.com.br/index.php/user/login/">
<legend>Login</legend>
<p><label>email:</label> <input type="email"/></p>
<p><label>senha:</label> <input type="password"/></p>
<p><label>enviar</label> <input type="submit"/></p>
```

```
<form id="cadastro" method="post" action="http://www.seudominio.com.br/index.php/user/cadastro/">
    <legend>Cadastro</legend>
    <p><label>nome:</label> <input type="text"/></p>
    <p><label>email:</label> <input type="email"/></p>
    <p><label>senha:</label> <input type="password"/></p>
    <p><label>Repita a senha:</label> <input type="password"/></p>
    <p><label>enviar</label> <input type="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

Pronto, agora dentro do seu controller você pode recuperar os campos com:

```
$_POST['nome_do_campo'];
```

Lembre-se que seus input devem conter um atributo chamado "name" para retornar via POST.

Answer (score 0):

Também pode usar o helper  form do codeigniter e chamar o post assim:

```
$this->load->helper('form');  
$email = $this->input->post('email');
```

Referência: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html